# Receiver email address

Tags: transactions, address, traceability, email

Can the receiver's email address be obtained from the Bitcoin address? I accidentally sent money to this address:

```
14gpxmEMrzCpEEp2GZhbUfP5cgBmwtVs9T
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, an email address cannot be obtained from a Bitcoin address. Addresses can be generated on an offline PC by someone living in a desert who doesn't even have an email address.

Most wallets won't ask you to provide any personal information, they won't even ask you which country you live in, let alone contact information like an email address. Such personal information usually only obtained when you register for an account on a website. I, for example, never gave an email address of mine out to obtain a wallet. And even if the owner of that address used a web wallet which requires them to state their email address (web wallets don't even have to do that, it's just something they usually do), this doesn't mean that anyone but the service provider has access to that contact information. Depending on where the service provider is located, it might even be illegal for them to share users' contact information with others.

I don't know where you got that address from but if you sent money to a random address, chances are that no one has access to it and the UTXO generated is forever unspendable.

Comment: https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/address/14gpxmEMrzCpEEp2GZhbUfP5cgBmwtVs9T - someone has access to this address and was mostly very grateful for the free coins :)

Comment: @Alex Yes, someone created a transaction sending the funds to 2 different addresses. That transaction was first heard of about 4 hours after I wrote my answer, though, and has yet to be confirmed. But thanks for the hint. I checked before writing my answer but I of course would not have checked, again. This means that OP didn't pick a random address but it it from somewhere. The site you linked to seems to have a bug, btw.: It clearly shows that the incoming transaction is confirmed and the outgoing one isn't, yet it says that the address's confirmed balance is 0.